# If my async function successfully completed, is this the correct way to then do something else?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code. The idea is that it will create a record in the `groups` collection. If successful, then it should create a record in a different collection - the `groups_UID` collection. Is this the correct way to do this? I feel like it might be wrong because `async/await` are normally used separately from `.then()`, right? Or maybe I'm just misremembering something here.

```
await docRef.set({
      'adminUID': currentUID,
      'adminUsername': currentUsername,
      'createDate': timestamp,
      'groupID': groupID,
      'groupName': groupName,
    }).then((value) async {
      print('##MyApp## database createGroupFS groups record added');

      CollectionReference groupsUIDCollection = firestore.collection('groups_' + currentUID);
      final groupsUIDDocRef = groupsUIDCollection.doc();

      await groupsUIDDocRef.set({
        'adminUID': currentUID,
        'adminUsername': currentUsername,
        'createDate': timestamp,
        'groupID': groupID,
        'groupName': groupName,
      }).then((value) {
        print('##MyApp## database createGroupFS groups_UID record added');
        returnVal = groupID;
      }).catchError((error) {
        print('##MyApp## database createGroupFS groups_UID ERROR: ' + error.toString());
        returnVal = '';
      });
    }).catchError((error) {
      print('##MyApp## database createGroupFS groups ERROR: ' + error.toString());
      returnVal = '';
    });
```

Comment: Yes, mixing `await` with `Future.then`/`Future.catchError` is a code smell.  Just use `await`; it's much easier to read and to reason about.

Comment: @jamesdlin then how do I re-write this so that I only create the second record if the first record, i.e. the first async function, executes successfully?

Answer (score 1):

You should either use one or another. I prefer using `async/await` with `try/catch` because I find it more readable. So in your example solution would be:

```
try {
  // if it fails it goes to the catch part
  final res = await docRef.set({
    'adminUID': currentUID,
    'adminUsername': currentUsername,
    'createDate': timestamp,
    'groupID': groupID,
    'groupName': groupName,
  });
  // it will continue going on success
  print('##MyApp## database createGroupFS groups record added');

  CollectionReference groupsUIDCollection =
      firestore.collection('groups_' + currentUID);
  final groupsUIDDocRef = groupsUIDCollection.doc();

  try {
    // same thing here
    final res2 = await groupsUIDDocRef.set({
      'adminUID': currentUID,
      'adminUsername': currentUsername,
      'createDate': timestamp,
      'groupID': groupID,
      'groupName': groupName,
    });
    // success
    print('##MyApp## database createGroupFS groups_UID record added');
    returnVal = groupID;
  } catch (error) {
    // error happened on groupsUIDDocRef.set
    print('##MyApp## database createGroupFS groups_UID ERROR: ' +
        error.toString());
    returnVal = '';
  }
} catch (error) {
  // error happened on docRef.set
  print(
      '##MyApp## database createGroupFS groups ERROR: ' + error.toString());
  returnVal = '';
}
```

Comment: So is the general principle here that if the `await` was successful, run another `try/catch`, otherwise go to the `catch` block? Program flow with `async/await` is done with 2 paths created by `try` and `catch`?

Comment: Why did you use `final res = ...` to assign the result of the `await` to a variable and then not do anything with this variable?

Comment: You can use only one `try/catch`, but if you want to react differently on different errors, that's the case to use 2 or more. And regarding the `final res` variable, I just copied your code and assigned the result to the `res` variable, just like your `then` was returning `value` and you haven't used it, I did not use `res` either.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `try/catch` as it will give you more flexibility when the `awaited` function throws error.

the syntax should be,

```
try{
var result= await someFunction();
//perform action 
}catch(e,stacktrace){
//handle error
}
```